# Excel Vba FileSystemObject Find File in Subfolder And Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Yesterday ı try to find if file exists in folder by first 6 [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364867/excel-vba-filesystemobject-find-file?noredirect=1#comment129562955_73364867).
Today ı want to find file in subfolder by first 6 character and give hyperlink to excel cell of file path with full name. ı just can check if it exists or not. Could you assist me to type this code?

```
Const RootPath1 As String = "X:\DOSYALAR\ÜRETİM\FORMLAR"
Const SeriCol As Long = 3
Dim iCnt As Integer
iCnt = fn_LastRow(Sheets("Data")) + 1
Dim h2 As Hyperlink
Dim h2_name As String: h2_name = ws.Cells(iCnt, SeriCol)


With ws
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(iCnt, SeriCol), _
 Address:=RootPath1, _
 ScreenTip:="Click to open order form", _
 TextToDisplay:=h2_name
End With
```

Comment: In the linked question, `strFileExists` will be the filename, if a matching file exists.

Comment: `strFileExists ` it must be completely match but ı want to match first 6 character. And ı don't want to check if its exists or not. And also file can be in subfolder. I couldn't find file  and get path it

Comment: `strFileExits` is the filename. So yes, you need it here too (along with `Dir`). Have you tried incorporating it yet? Or have you tried using `FileSystemObject`?

Comment: Nope. I am Newbei here.